what are "const-correctness" rules for initializing/binding pointers and references to pointers?

Given that there are 4 "constness" flavors of pointers:
       B       *        = non-const pointer to non-const B

 const B       *        = non-const pointer to     const B aka
       B const *        = non-const pointer to     const B

       B       * const  =     const pointer to non-const B

 const B       * const  =     const pointer to     const B aka
       B const * const  =     const pointer to     const B

where "non-const pointer" means that you can change the pointer (e.g. p = NULL) and "non-const B" means you can change the B (e.g. *p = 0).
What are the actual rules that govern when you can:

initialize a pointer p of one const flavor with a pointer q of another const flavor?
initialize a reference r to a pointer of one const flavor with a pointer q of another const flavor?

This question is only about const-ness, so assume all pointers point to the same base type B that is not itself a pointer.
By "initialize" I mean:

initializing a variable p/r you just declared using q:

P p = q;


passing a function actual parameter q to a function's formal parameter p/r

void myfunc(P p) {}
myfunc(q);


returning q from a func with return type P/R

P myfunc() { return q; }

Previously, I had blissfully ignorantly assumed that it was as simple as "for the const-ness of the pointer and, separately, the const-ness of B, as long as you don't try to "take away const" (i.e. as long as p/r have const wherever q does) it will work.
However, when I actually tried it with all 16 p and 16 r combos, I realized there's a lot more going on.  Not only is the behavior asymmetric for p and r, but within each case there are strange asymmetries.
What are the exact rules which govern these const cases and where can I find them in the spec?
Here are all 16 p (pointer) initialization combinations (right hand side is pseudocode to make it more readable).  Initializations which cause compile errors are marked // err:
/*p00*/ B       *        p  =  B       *       q;
/*p01*/ B       * const  p  =  B       *       q;
/*p02*/ B const *        p  =  B       *       q;
/*p03*/ B const * const  p  =  B       *       q;
        
/*p04*/ B       *        p  =  B       * const q;
/*p05*/ B       * const  p  =  B       * const q;
/*p06*/ B const *        p  =  B       * const q;
/*p07*/ B const * const  p  =  B       * const q;

/*p08*/ B       *        p  =  B const *       q; // err
/*p09*/ B       * const  p  =  B const *       q; // err
/*p10*/ B const *        p  =  B const *       q;
/*p11*/ B const * const  p  =  B const *       q;
        
/*p12*/ B       *        p  =  B const * const q; // err
/*p13*/ B       * const  p  =  B const * const q; // err
/*p14*/ B const *        p  =  B const * const q;
/*p15*/ B const * const  p  =  B const * const q;

Some examples of surprising (to me) results include p00-p07 where we seem to be able to add or remove pointer constness at will.
Here are all 16 r (reference) initialization combinations (right hand side is pseudocode to make it more readable; assume the right hand side is just the lvalue q in real code).  Initializations which cause compile errors are marked // err:
/*r00*/ B       *       &r  =  B       *       q; 
/*r01*/ B       * const &r  =  B       *       q;
/*r02*/ B const *       &r  =  B       *       q; // err
/*r03*/ B const * const &r  =  B       *       q;
        
/*r04*/ B       *       &r  =  B       * const q; // err
/*r05*/ B       * const &r  =  B       * const q;
/*r06*/ B const *       &r  =  B       * const q; // err
/*r07*/ B const * const &r  =  B       * const q;

/*r08*/ B       *       &r  =  B const *       q; // err
/*r09*/ B       * const &r  =  B const *       q; // err
/*r10*/ B const *       &r  =  B const *       q;
/*r11*/ B const * const &r  =  B const *       q;
        
/*r12*/ B       *       &r  =  B const * const q; // err
/*r13*/ B       * const &r  =  B const * const q; // err
/*r14*/ B const *       &r  =  B const * const q; // err
/*r15*/ B const * const &r  =  B const * const q;

The pattern of which work and do not (in particular r02 where we cannot add B const vs r07 where we suddenly can add B const) is quite confusing.

Indeed there is a lot going on.
Initialization is covered in the C++ spec in dcl.init.
The section dcl.init.1 confirms that the rules are the same for all 3 syntactic contexts (variable initialization, passing arguments, returning values).
The section dcl.init.16 describes many many different cases of initialization.  We can see there are different rules for initializing references, strings, arrays, and many other types.
Pointer Cases
Since every pointer has two constnesses, let's introduce a term.  Let's refer to the const after the * as as the "pointer constness" (some may call it "outer constness" too) since it affects whether you can change the pointer (e.g. p = NULL):
B const * const  p  =  B const * const q;
          ^^^^^                  ^^^^^
          ^^^^^                  ^^^^^
     pointer constness     pointer constness

and let's refer to the const before the * as the "B constness" (some may call it the "inner constness" too) since it affects whether you can change the B (e.g. *p = 0):
B const * const  p  =  B const * const q;
  ^^^^^                  ^^^^^
  ^^^^^                  ^^^^^
B constness            B constness

Because p is not a reference, string, array, or any of the other special cases, our initialization falls into the catch-all case dcl.init.16.9 (the same catch-all used for int and other boring types), which says:

Otherwise, the initial value of the object being initialized is the (possibly converted) value of the initializer expression.
A standard conversion sequence ([conv]) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression to the cv-unqualified version of the destination type; no user-defined conversions are considered....

The "cv" refers to "const and volatile."  It's unclear what the spec means by "to the cv-unqualified version" but fortunately the matter is cleared up by note 8 (reformatted with east const for consistency):

An expression of type “cv1 T” can initialize an object of type “cv2 T” independently of the cv-qualifiers cv1 and cv2.

int       a;
int const b = a;
int       c = b;

This helpful note shows that in an initialization under the rules of dcl.init.16.9, we get a "free pass" to add or remove the one outer layer of const as we like.  For example, we can initialize a const int with an int or an int with a const int.
Section dcl.init.16.9 applies not only to ints but to pointers too.  And just as an int can be const or not, a pointer can be const or not (its "pointer constness").  So it is just as valid to say:
int *       a;
int * const b = a;
int *       c = b;

In other words, when initializing a pointer with another pointer, we also get a "free pass" to add or remove the "pointer constness."
This explains why the following test cases compile.  These cases leave the B constness the same, but they try to change the "pointer constness" in every possible combination, and C++ is happy to let us attempt any combination of "pointer constness":
/*p00*/ B       *        p  =  B       *       q;
/*p01*/ B       * const  p  =  B       *       q;
/*p04*/ B       *        p  =  B       * const q;
/*p05*/ B       * const  p  =  B       * const q;

same for these examples:
/*p10*/ B const *        p  =  B const *       q;
/*p11*/ B const * const  p  =  B const *       q;
/*p14*/ B const *        p  =  B const * const q;
/*p15*/ B const * const  p  =  B const * const q;

So what happens if we leave the "pointer constness" the same but we try to change the "B constness"?  Here are all the examples:
/*p02*/ B const *        p  =  B       *       q;
/*p05*/ B       * const  p  =  B       * const q;
/*p07*/ B const * const  p  =  B       * const q;
/*p08*/ B       *        p  =  B const *       q; // err
/*p10*/ B const *        p  =  B const *       q;
/*p13*/ B       * const  p  =  B const * const q; // err

Here we can see the "intuitive" pattern that most of us thought was the whole picture: every time we try to change the "B constness" from const q to non-const p, the compiler errs.  This makes sense because we don't want to give p access to modify B when q forbids that.
This intuitive sense is codified when dcl.init.16.9 says "A standard conversion sequence (conv) will be used, if necessary, to convert the initializer expression..."
When doing the initializations above, p and q have different B constness, and so it's necessary to do a standard conversion (unlike the "pointer constness" where we get a free pass as explained above).  The relevant section of conv is conv.qual since const (and volatile) are known as "qualifiers".
conv.qual is frankly a bitch to read.  It is trying to handle a lot of special cases (some of which we will need below).  But suffice it to say that:

the "B constness" in our current example is called cv1 in the spec (not cv0: cv0 is the "pointer constness" and it plays no role in the conv.qual algorithm).
if you follow the complex algorithm for our case of single-layer pointers, you will see it implements the intuitive idea of "when going from q to p, you can add const, but you can't take const away."

So that explains all of p01-p15 (the only cases we didn't cover are where p and q have identical constness, so we know they will compile).  Whew.
Reference Cases
The initializer section dcl.init.16.2 tells us that reference initializations are subject to the completely different rules in dcl.init.ref.
We are doing the case of initializing lvalue references (&) with an lvalue on the right hand side (q), which is covered by decl.init.ref.5:

A reference to type “cv1 T1” is initialized by an expression of type “cv2 T2” as follows ... If the reference is an lvalue reference and the initializer expression is an lvalue ... and “cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2” ... then the reference binds to the initializer expression lvalue

So we need to look at the definition of "reference-compatible" in decl.init.ref.4:

“cv1 T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2 T2” if a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 T2” can be converted to the type “pointer to cv1 T1” via a standard conversion sequence (conv).

The spec is telling us that a reference to any type T:
T &r  = t;

must follow the same constness rules as if r were a pointer pp to the same type T:
T *pp  = &t;

Let's apply that to our situation, where T itself is a pointer type.
The spec is telling us that our reference to a pointer type:
B [const] * [const] &r  =  B [const] * [const] q;

must follow the same constness rules as if r were a pointer pp to the same pointer type:
B [const] * [const] *pp  =  B [const] * [const] &q;

Wow, so we're back to pointers and our old friend conv.  But now we have two levels of pointer!
So the question of which of r00-r15 should compile comes down to which of the following pp00-pp15 should compile:
/*pp00*/ B       *       *      pp  =  B       *       &q; 
/*pp01*/ B       * const *      pp  =  B       *       &q;
/*pp02*/ B const *       *      pp  =  B       *       &q; // err
/*pp03*/ B const * const *      pp  =  B       *       &q;
        
/*pp04*/ B       *       *      pp  =  B       * const &q; // err
/*pp05*/ B       * const *      pp  =  B       * const &q;
/*pp06*/ B const *       *      pp  =  B       * const &q; // err
/*pp07*/ B const * const *      pp  =  B       * const &q;

/*pp08*/ B       *       *      pp  =  B const *       &q; // err
/*pp09*/ B       * const *      pp  =  B const *       &q; // err
/*pp10*/ B const *       *      pp  =  B const *       &q;
/*pp11*/ B const * const *      pp  =  B const *       &q;
        
/*pp12*/ B       *       *      pp  =  B const * const &q; // err
/*pp13*/ B       * const *      pp  =  B const * const &q; // err
/*pp14*/ B const *       *      pp  =  B const * const &q; // err
/*pp15*/ B const * const *      pp  =  B const * const &q;

Notice how each line actually has three levels of constness:
/*pp15*/ B const * const *      pp  =  B const * const &q; (&q is const)
           ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^         ^^^^^   ^^^^^            ^^^^^  
            cv2     cv1     cv0            cv2     cv1              cv0

The terminology cv0-cv2 matches that seen in conv.qual.
You can think of cv0 as the "pointer constness" of pp and &q.  As we learned above, C++ will let us change cv0 in any way without compiler error.  So cv0 plays no role in our answer.
You can think of cv1 and cv2 as two layers of "B constness".
To figure out which of pp00-pp15 are valid, we must arduously decode the complex algorithm in conv.qual.
You have to trudge through it to really convince yourself, but here I will present the key points. Considering cv1 and cv2:

It is a compiler error if we try to change any cvN from const in q to non-const in p (this is our intuitive sense from above), and
If cv2 differs between q and p, then p's cv1 must be const, otherwise it is a compiler error

It is this weird condition #2 that causes the unintuitive behaviors (like why r07 is OK but r02 is not, even though in both cases we just add const to p in the same place).
Condition #2 was added to handle a borderline case that you can read about in conv.qual note 1.
So that explains all of r01-r15 as well!
Can't C++ just be simple?
